# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) after spring18 in managed package

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, spring18

I have visual force page in which we are trying to access a static resource

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.<ResourceNAme>}" />
```

But somehow I am getting above error for static resource.
Above code for working until Friday. So I guess only reason could be spring 18 release updates. 
Have salesforce changed anything related to static resource.

Comment: is it public? maybe the static resource access was changed to private by someone =P or the static resource deleted all together

Comment: no it is public

Comment: I think the issue is somewhere else. It shouldn't be a Spring 18 issue.

Comment: in browser console error shown is Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

Comment: @ManjotSingh Did you manage to fix this issue? Apparently, I am facing the same problem after Summer 19 
 release.      https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/266296/after-summer19-release-view-all-on-custom-lightening-component-related-list

Comment: @ManjotSingh Is this issue fixed? Actually, I was using <link> tag so my format was working but when I downloaded the stylesheet and put it in static resource, its giving me the same error.