# After Summer'19 release - "View All" on custom lightning component related list not loading

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, release

After Summer'19 release - "View All" on custom lightning component related list not loading.

When users click on "View All" to view all the records, it takes to separate page but nothing loads. Is anyone facing the same issue?

Code Below

```
public without sharing class SummaryTableController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Object getParentObjectName(Id recordId){
        recordId = Id.valueOf(recordId);
        String sObjLabel = recordId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getLabel();
        String sObjAPI = recordId.getSobjectType().getDescribe().getName();
        String nameAPI;
        if (sObjAPI != 'Case'){ nameAPI = 'Name'; } else { nameAPI = 'CaseNumber';}
        String query = 'Select ' + nameAPI +' From ' + sObjAPI + ' Where Id =: recordId';
        sObject record = database.query(query);
        Map<String,String> names = new Map<String,String>();
        names.put('parentObjLabel', sObjLabel);
        names.put('parentObjAPI',sObjAPI);
        names.put('parentRecName',string.valueOf(record.get(nameAPI)));
        return names;
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getIconName(String sObjectName){
        
        String u;
        
        List<Schema.DescribeTabSetResult> tabSetDesc = Schema.describeTabs();
        List<Schema.DescribeTabResult> tabDesc = new List<Schema.DescribeTabResult>();
        List<Schema.DescribeIconResult> iconDesc = new List<Schema.DescribeIconResult>();
        
        for(Schema.DescribeTabSetResult tsr : tabSetDesc) { tabDesc.addAll(tsr.getTabs()); }
        
        for(Schema.DescribeTabResult tr : tabDesc) {
            if( sObjectName == tr.getSobjectName() ) {
                if( tr.isCustom() == true ) {
                    iconDesc.addAll(tr.getIcons());
                } else {
                    u = 'standard:' + sObjectName.toLowerCase();
                }
            }
        }
        for (Schema.DescribeIconResult ir : iconDesc) {
            if (ir.getContentType() == 'image/svg+xml'){
                u = 'custom:' + ir.getUrl().substringBetween('custom/','.svg').substringBefore('_');
                break;
            }
        }            
        
        return u;
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled 
    public static String getObjLabel(String objAPIName){
        system.debug(objAPIName);
        List<Schema.DescribeSObjectResult> describeSobjectsResult = Schema.describeSObjects(new List<String>{objAPIName}); // this can accept list of strings, we describe only one object here
        String objectLabel = describeSobjectsResult[0].getLabelPlural();
        return objectLabel;
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Integer getCountRecords(String recId, String relatedObjectName, String conditions, String relationship) {
        // Charles 01/11/2018 Get Profile Name, Schools and Units
        Id userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        User currentUser = [Select profileId, Faculty_School__c, Business_Unit__c From User Where Id =: userId];
        String FacultySchool = currentUser.Faculty_School__c;
        String BusinessUnit = currentUser.Business_Unit__c;
        List<Id> oppAccIds;
        if(String.isNotBlank(conditions) && conditions.indexOf('oppAccIds') != -1) {
            oppAccIds = new List<id>(new Map<Id, Opportunity>(
                            [select Id, name from Opportunity where id in 
                             (select opportunity__c from AccountOpportunityRelation__c where Account__c = :recId)
                            ]).keySet());
        }
        
        Integer count;
        
        Id recordId = Id.valueOf(recId);
        
        try{
            count = Database.countQuery(countQueryGenerator(relatedObjectName, relationship,recordId,conditions));
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('Exception: '+ e);
        }
        
        return count;
    }
    
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<sObject> getRecords(String recId, String fields, String relatedObjectName, 
                                           String conditions, String sortOrder, String relationship, String recordLimit, String offset) {
        // Charles 01/11/2018 Get Profile Name, Schools and Units
        Id userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        User currentUser = [Select profileId, Faculty_School__c, Business_Unit__c From User Where Id =: userId];
        String FacultySchool = currentUser.Faculty_School__c;
        String BusinessUnit = currentUser.Business_Unit__c;
        List<Id> oppAccIds;
        if(String.isNotBlank(conditions) && conditions.indexOf('oppAccIds') != -1) {
            oppAccIds = new List<id>(new Map<Id, Opportunity>(
                            [select Id, name from Opportunity where id in 
                             (select opportunity__c from AccountOpportunityRelation__c where Account__c = :recId)
                            ]).keySet());
        }
        
        List<sObject> relatedRecords = new List<sObject>();
        
        Id recordId = Id.valueOf(recId);
        Schema.SObjectType objectType = recordId.getSObjectType();
        String sObjectName = objectType.getDescribe().getName();
        DescribeSObjectResult objectResult = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(relatedObjectName).getDescribe();
        String finalFields = '';
        
        for (String field : fields.split(',')){
            field = field.trim();
            if (string.valueOf(objectResult.fields.getMap().get(field).getDescribe().getType()) == 'REFERENCE' ){
                finalFields = finalFields + ', ' + objectResult.fields.getMap().get(field).getDescribe().getRelationshipName() + '.Name' ;
            } else {
                finalFields = finalFields + ', ' + field;
            }
        }
        
        try{
            relatedRecords = Database.query(queryGenerator(finalFields.substring(1), relatedObjectName, relationship,recordLimit,offset, recordId,conditions,sortOrder));
            System.debug('RelatedRecords: ' + relatedRecords);
            
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('Exception: '+ e);
        }
        
        return relatedRecords;
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<ColumnWrapper> getColumns(String recId, String fields, String relatedObjectName) {
        List<ColumnWrapper> columns = new List<ColumnWrapper>();
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldDescriptionMap = getFieldDescriptionDetails(relatedObjectName);
        List<String> fieldNamesList = fields.split(',');
        Set<String> fieldNamesSet = new Set<String>(fieldNamesList); 
        DescribeSObjectResult objectResult = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(relatedObjectName).getDescribe();
        
        for(String field : fieldNamesSet){
            field = field.trim();
            if(field.equalsIgnoreCase('Name')){
                TypeAttributes typeAttrib = new TypeAttributes('_self', new Label('Name'),null);
                columns.add(new ColumnWrapper('linkName', 'url', 'Name', typeAttrib, true));
            } else if (field.equalsIgnoreCase('Subject') && !relatedObjectName.equalsIgnoreCase('Case')){
                TypeAttributes typeAttrib = new TypeAttributes('_self', new Label('Subject'),null);
                columns.add(new ColumnWrapper('linkName', 'url', 'Subject', typeAttrib, false));
            } else if (field.equalsIgnoreCase('CaseNumber')){
                TypeAttributes typeAttrib = new TypeAttributes('_self', new Label('CaseNumber'),null);
                columns.add(new ColumnWrapper('linkName', 'url', 'CaseNumber', typeAttrib, false));
            } else{
                columns.add(createColumns(objectResult, field));
            }
        }
        
        System.debug('COLUMNS: ' + columns);
        return columns;
    }
    
    //relationship is deprecated    
    private static String queryGenerator(String fields, String relatedObjectName, String relationship,
                                            String recordLimit,String offset, String recordId,String conditions,String sortOrder){
        recordLimit = recordLimit == null  ? ' ' : ' LIMIT ' + string.valueOf(recordLimit);
        offset = offset == null ? ' ' : ' OFFSET '+ string.valueOf(offset);
        conditions = conditions == null || conditions == '' ? ' ' : ' WHERE ' + conditions ;
        sortOrder = sortOrder == null || sortOrder =='' ? ' ' : ' Order By ' + sortOrder;
        String query = 'SELECT Id,' + fields + ' FROM ' + relatedObjectName + conditions + sortOrder + recordLimit + offset;
        system.debug(query);
        return query;
    }
    
    //relationship is deprecated
    private static String countQueryGenerator(String relatedObjectName, String relationship,String recordId,String conditions){
        conditions = conditions == null || conditions == '' ? ' ' : ' WHERE ' + conditions ;
        String query = 'SELECT count() FROM ' + relatedObjectName + conditions ;
        System.debug(query);
        return query;
    }
    
    private static ColumnWrapper createColumns(DescribeSObjectResult objectResult, String field){
        
        DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = objectResult.fields.getMap().get(field).getDescribe();
        
        if(String.valueOf(fieldResult.getType()) == 'REFERENCE'){
            String relationshipName = fieldResult.getRelationshipName().removeend('__r');
            if (relationshipName.equalsIgnoreCase('RecordType')) {
                relationshipName = fieldResult.getReferenceTo()[0].getDescribe().getLabel();
            }
            return new ColumnWrapper(fieldResult.getRelationshipName()+'_Id', 'url', relationshipName, new TypeAttributes('_self', new Label(fieldResult.getRelationshipName()+'_Name'),fieldResult.getRelationshipName()), false);   
        }else if (String.valueOf(fieldResult.getType()) == 'BOOLEAN'){
            return new ColumnWrapper(fieldResult.getName(), 'Boolean', fieldResult.getLabel(), new CellAttributes(new Label(fieldResult.getName()+'_chk'),'left'), true);
        } else {
            return new ColumnWrapper(fieldResult.getName(), String.valueOf(fieldResult.getType()), fieldResult.getLabel(), true);
        }
    }
    
    private static Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> getFieldDescriptionDetails(String objectName){
        
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> objectDescriptionMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        
        Schema.Describesobjectresult result = objectDescriptionMap.get(objectName).getDescribe();
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldsDescriptionMap = result.fields.getMap();
        
        return fieldsDescriptionMap;
    }
    
    //Wrapper class for column attributes
    public class ColumnWrapper{
        
        @AuraEnabled
        public String fieldName {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String type {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String label {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public TypeAttributes typeAttributes{get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public CellAttributes cellAttributes{get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled        
        public Boolean sortable {get;set;}
        
        public ColumnWrapper(String name, String dataType, String fieldLabel, Boolean sortable){
            this.fieldName = name;
            this.type = dataType;
            this.label = fieldLabel;
            this.sortable = sortable;
        }
        
        public ColumnWrapper(String name, String dataType, String fieldLabel, TypeAttributes labelName, Boolean sortable){
            this.fieldName = name;
            this.type = dataType;
            this.label = fieldLabel;
            this.TypeAttributes = labelName;
            this.sortable = sortable;
        }
        public ColumnWrapper(String name, String dataType, String fieldLabel, CellAttributes labelName, Boolean sortable){
            this.fieldName = name;
            this.type = dataType;
            this.label = fieldLabel;
            this.CellAttributes = labelName;
            this.sortable = sortable;
        }
        
    }
    
    public class TypeAttributes{
        @AuraEnabled
        public Label label {get;set;}  
        @AuraEnabled
        public String target {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String relationship{get;set;}
        
        public TypeAttributes(String target, Label label,String relationship){
            this.target = target;
            this.Label = label;
            this.relationship = relationship;
        }      
    }
    
    public class cellAttributes{
        @AuraEnabled
        public Label iconName {get;set;}  
        @AuraEnabled
        public String iconPosition {get;set;}
        
        public cellAttributes(Label iconName,String iconPosition){
            this.iconName = iconName;
            this.iconPosition = iconPosition;
        }      
    }
    
    public class Label{
        @AuraEnabled
        public String fieldName {get;set;}
        
        public Label(String fieldName){
            this.fieldName = fieldName;
        }
    }  
}`
```

Error in debug mode.
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Can you add the code you are using for custom lightening component related list?

Comment: I have added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since summer release there is a change in pageReference.state it should now have c__ appended in the properties. Applying  these change in those components would resolve the issue.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_namespace_prefix_cruc_reminder.htm